# Does this look like a termite?

Tags: termite

I found a suspicious looking insect in my kitchen counter top, and I'm wondering if it was a termite. Can anyone who are familiar with termite confirm whether or not the insect in the picture below is a termite? I recall that the length of the insect was about quarter inch (~ 6mm.)
[image]

I also noticed small white, almost transparent wings floating on top of the pool in my backyard after a couple of rainy days. I guess probably there were a swarm of those insects in my backyard a couple of days ago. Should I worry about any potential termite infestation?

By the way, for anyone who are curious, I live in northern California (Bay area) where termites are common problems.

Comment: It would be helpful if you would edit into your question where in the world you are. Insects vary by county/region.  Also has the picture been magnified? How big are these bugs actually?

Comment: You need to worry if they are inside the house. If they are swarming outside, then typically not a worry (assuming you live in a region where termites are common)

Comment: I updated my question with the region I live in and the size of the insect I observed

Comment: By the way, if it's a termite, is the color black common for termites?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a termite to me, The body is thick all the way back. Ants have a narrow body in the center. Make sure to check around your foundation and look for evidence especially where the dirt is close to the wood. It is possible that a swarm just arrived and that one came into the house through a door or window. With Termites and Carpenter ants it is best to be proactive because they can do a lot of damage in a short period of time. If you are not able to do the inspection under the house it might be worthwhile to hire a pest control company to do the inspection.